# Код работает в режиме отладки, но в обычном режиме вылетает

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

При нажатии на кнопку из БД подтягваются данные и выводятся на форму.в отладчике все как надо работает.В обычном режиме - вылет.В БД все таблицы, связи EF создал нормально.Ниже код события кнопки и модели БД

```
public class Backgrounds
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public byte[] TitleImage {get;set;}
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
 public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Money { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<Servers> Servers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Backgrounds> Backgrounds { get; set; }

}

private void backgrounds_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var AuthorizedUser = _context.User.First(x => x.Id == UserId);
            var ListOfServers = _context.Backgrounds.Take(18).AsQueryable();
            DataList.Children.Clear();

            foreach (var it in ListOfServers)
            {
                if (AuthorizedUser.Backgrounds.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == it.Id)!=null)
                {
                    viewer v = new viewer();
                    v.ObjId = it.Id;
                    v.Name.Content = it.Name;
                    v.Price.Content = it.Price;
                    if (it.TitleImage != null)
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(it.TitleImage))
                        {
                            var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                            ImageSource IS = decoder.Frames[0];
                            v.image.Source = IS;
                        }
                    v.Padding = new Thickness(5);
                    DataList.Children.Add(v);
                }
            }          
        }
```

Comment: Что значит "вылетает"? Приведите текст ошибки.

Comment: @AK рекращена работа программы. Windows осуществляет поиск способа устранения этой ошибки

Comment: `try {/*тут ваш код*/} catch(Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error"); }`